# Phone mounted read-only drives stacking up at /media

Tags: 18.04, automount

My mobile phone has a read-only volume on it to easily provide drivers for Windows. This of course is not needed on Ubuntu, but this volume mounts every time the phone is connected by USB. If the phone is removed without ejecting this read only volume, the folder is still kept at /media/USERNAME/... . With every new connection, another numbered folder is added which will leave a heap of empty folders behind cluttering /media/USERNAME that can only be deleted by root user.

How to prevent this?

Comment: *"If the phone is removed without ejecting"* .... *"How to prevent this?"* - I think you've answered your own question.  You should properly disconnect volumes before unplugging them

Comment: Well there are several caveats. 1st, a plug may me slipping out. Yes, things like that happen. So as a non-priveleged user I will have to call the system administrator to clean up the mess every time the cable slipped?  2nd, if there are multiple drives, ejecting one of them often closes down the whole phone drive, forceably ejecting the other volumes. With the same result.